# Concatenate File name, remove leading and trailing whitespaces from strings in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, concatenation, cmd

I'm trying to concatenate file name (fileName) behind a directory path (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs) and before a file extension(.log) in batch, but I think because my fileName contains leading and trailing whitespaces, the cmd.exe does not recognize the concatenated path (logPath). Any ideas?

```
 FOR %%G IN (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\*.properties) DO (
   Set fileName= %%~nxG
   REM echo !fileName!
   REM java -jar Test.jar %%~nxG > Logs\%%~nxG.log
   set logPath=%C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs\%%!fileName!%%.log%
   Echo !logPath!
   REM print each line in each of the log files
    REM FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g in (!logPath!) DO (
   REM echo %%g
   REM )
   pause
   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your filename has a leading and trailing space?  Normally it's not possible, that a filename ends with a space.

Your variable `filename` has a leading space because you should avoid spaces when using the `set` command.
Also the creation of the `logPath` seems to be wrong.

A corrected version could look like

```
FOR %%G IN (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\*.properties) DO (
   Set "fileName=%%~nxG"
   REM echo !fileName!
   REM java -jar Test.jar %%~nxG > Logs\%%~nxG.log
   set "logPath=C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs\!fileName!.log"
   Echo !logPath!
   REM print each line in each of the log files
    REM FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g in (!logPath!) DO (
   REM echo %%g
   REM )
   pause
)
```